# Tensor product of fields may not be a field

Tags: field-theory, tensor-products

Let L and N be field extension of K.
Tensor product of L and N over K is always field？

If there are counterexamples, I would be appreciated if you could give me an example and explanation.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_fields   "... it can contain nonzero nilpotent elements...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given any proper field extension $K \subset L$, the tensor product $L \otimes_K L$ is never a field, because the kernel of the multiplication map $L \otimes_K L \to L$ is a nonzero proper ideal.

Comment: Could you tell me why the kernel is nonzero proper ideal ?

Comment: @kleinfour For any $x \in L \setminus K$, $x \otimes 1-1 \otimes x$ is a nonzero element of the kernel. Also, the kernel obviously does not contain $1 \otimes 1$, because $1 \cdot 1=1 \ne 0 \in L$.

Comment: Could you tell me why x tensor 1 - 1 tensor x is nonzero ?